# High RAM Consumption with MariaDB

Tags: memory, mariadb, replication, ram

People that I would like to ask a question about.

I have a replica between a laptop and a server.

On the server I have no problems

But on the laptop ...

With Time, you notice that the RAM increases ... Until you reach the limit ... When you reach the limit, the MariaDB service is restarted.

What is the reason for the increase in RAM ...

Server version: **10.1.32-MariaDB MariaDB Server**

[image: increase in memory - 1]

[image: increase in memory - 2]

[image: increase in memory - 3]

Excuse me my English is not very good

```
socket          = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

slave-net-timeout = 30

binlog_ignore_db = mysql
binlog_ignore_db = zoom
binlog_ignore_db = performance_schema
binlog_ignore_db = information_schema

binlog_do_db = TK09
replicate_do_db = TK09
binlog_ignore_db = TK09_user

log-bin=binlog
log-slave-updates=1

binlog_format=mixed

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 40M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have?